# Principal submatrix unitary matrix normal

Tags: matrices

Given a $n\times n$ unitary matrix $M$ with leading principal submatrix $S$ ($(n-1)\times (n-1)$, codimension $1$), is it true that $S$ is normal?

Answer (score 1):

Try e.g. $$ \pmatrix{1/2 & -1/2 & -\sqrt{2}/2\cr
                     1/2 & 5/6 & -\sqrt{2}/6\cr
                     \sqrt{2}/2 & -\sqrt{2}/6 & 2/3\cr} $$

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't even have to be selfadjoint. For instance, take 
$$
M=\frac12\,\begin{bmatrix} 
1&-1&1&-1 \\
1&1&1&1\\
-1&1&1&-1\\
-1&-1&1&1
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Comment: I found a counterexample earlier to my statement, thanks though!